# WebViewClient.onRenderProcessGone() not called on crashing WebView first

Tags: android, webview

I have an app that can have multiple WebViews at the same time. Every once in a while the app crashes with a native error

```
SIGTRAP: Trace/breakpoint trap
        at 0x7a587dd494(/data/app/com.android.chrome-7kzKsZs3wawWfQ1TQ0h58w==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a/libmonochrome.so:25011348)
```

I was able to track it down to a WebView renderer issue which i can simulate by loading a faulty javascript like `webView.evaluateJavascript("javascript:(function() { txt = \"a\"; while(1){ txt += \"a\"; } })();", null);`.
I am now trying to figure out what page causes the problem in the production app. For that I am overriding `WebViewClient.onRenderProcessGone()` and want to log the loaded URL at that point. The problem that I have is that, since I have multiple WebViews, I cannot be sure that `onRenderProcessGone()` is called first on the one that actually caused the crash.

From the WebViewClient doc: `Multiple WebView instances may be associated with a single render process. onRenderProcessGone will be called for each WebView that was affected.`

My question is, in `WebViewClient.onRenderProcessGone()`, how can I know which WebView/WebViewClient has caused the crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question got answered in the [android-webview-dev](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/android-webview-dev/MEAtYPfGx6Q) google group. Unfortunately there is currently no way to know which webview has crashed.